# group by 3 tables and count in empty functions the same as empty tables mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, group-by, nosql, nosql-aggregation

`
this is my document: i want to group by storeId,and 3 arrays diag.webForWeb, diag.webForStore and diag.storeForStore and make a  count even empty array:
something like that.

```
storeId; businessRulesWebForStore ; (vide); 100
$storeId; businessRulesWebForStore ; Cas 1; 1344
$storeId; businessRulesWebForStore ; Cas 2; 721
...
$storeId; businessRulesStoreForStore ; (vide); 100
$storeId; businessRulesStoreForStore ; Cas 1; 1344
...
$storeId; businessRulesWebForWeb; (vide); 100
$storeId; businessRulesWebForWeb; Cas 1; 1344
```

so this is what i want to achieve,if someone ca help me plz
I made a query like that but it does not count empty values
`

```
{ 
        "_id" : "0176#82054861", 
        "storeId" : "176", 
        "diag" : {
            "webForWeb" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "39", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD est livrable en point relais sur commande - en plus des quantités éventuellement disponible sur le PE - associé à un ENT (pas de controle de stock avant l'ATP dans ce cas)."
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "12", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD n'est pas en stock sur le site d'éxpédition - pas de livraison avec délais court éligible."
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "37", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD est livrable à domicile sur commande - en plus des quantités éventuellement disponible sur le PE - associé à un ENT (pas de controle de stock avant l'ATP dans ce cas)."
                }
            ], 
            "webForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "7", 
                    "label" : "Le stock magasin est <= 1 la référence n'est pas proposé en retrait 2 H"
                }
            ], 
            "storeForStore" : [

            ]
        }
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "0176#66228414", 
        "storeId" : "176", 
        "diag" : {
            "webForWeb" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "12", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD n'est pas en stock sur le site d'éxpédition - pas de livraison avec délais court éligible."
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "37", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD est livrable à domicile sur commande - en plus des quantités éventuellement disponible sur le PE - associé à un ENT (pas de controle de stock avant l'ATP dans ce cas)."
                }
            ], 
            "webForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "7", 
                    "label" : "Le stock magasin est <= 1 la référence n'est pas proposé en retrait 2 H"
                }
            ], 
            "storeForStore" : [

            ]
        }
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "0176#67494266", 
        "storeId" : "176", 
        "diag" : {
            "webForWeb" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "3", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence n'est pas commercialisée sur le magasin 380. ‘Mode de vente’ à non dans shopping manager. Contact : Chargé de Commercialisation du rayon auquel appartient la référence"
                }
            ], 
            "webForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "6", 
                    "label" : "L'article n'est pas vendu en ligne par le magasin exclusion PickUp dans MyStore"
                }
            ], 
            "storeForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "6", 
                    "label" : "Plus de stock sur un produit non suivi rupture définitive"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "0192#80036271", 
        "storeId" : "192", 
        "diag" : {
            "webForWeb" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "18", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence n'est pas éligible au sur commande - hors quantité disponible sur le PE. Option shopping manager 'Se limiter au stock dispo' cochée. Contact : chargé de Commercialisation'"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "12", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD n'est pas en stock sur le site d'éxpédition - pas de livraison avec délais court éligible."
                }
            ], 
            "webForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "18", 
                    "label" : "Les références en top 1 ne sont pas éligible au sur commande."
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "10", 
                    "label" : "Le stock magasin est >1 la référence est suivi Auto elle est éligible au Retrait 2H"
                }
            ], 
            "storeForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "5", 
                    "label" : "Disponible en magasin"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "0205#80036271", 
        "storeId" : "205", 
        "diag" : {
            "webForWeb" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "18", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence n'est pas éligible au sur commande - hors quantité disponible sur le PE. Option shopping manager 'Se limiter au stock dispo' cochée. Contact : chargé de Commercialisation'"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "12", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD n'est pas en stock sur le site d'éxpédition - pas de livraison avec délais court éligible."
                }
            ], 
            "webForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "7", 
                    "label" : "Le stock magasin est <= 1 la référence n'est pas proposé en retrait 2 H"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "30", 
                    "label" : "La référence associée à un top Réppro à 2 n'est pas proposé à la vente car le retrait magasin sur commande est désactivé au niveau du magasin"
                }
            ], 
            "storeForStore" : [

            ]
        }
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "0205#73683743", 
        "storeId" : "205", 
        "diag" : {
            "webForWeb" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "8", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence LAD est en stock sur le site d'expédition - livraison à domicile éligible avec délais courts"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "18", 
                    "label" : "Cette référence n'est pas éligible au sur commande - hors quantité disponible sur le PE. Option shopping manager 'Se limiter au stock dispo' cochée. Contact : chargé de Commercialisation'"
                }
            ], 
            "webForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "7", 
                    "label" : "Le stock magasin est <= 1 la référence n'est pas proposé en retrait 2 H"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "17", 
                    "label" : "Les références en top 0 ne sont pas éligible au sur commande."
                }
            ], 
            "storeForStore" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "6", 
                    "label" : "Plus de stock sur un produit non suivi rupture définitive"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

`
this is my document: i want to group by storeId,and 3 arrays diag.webForWeb, diag.webForStore and diag.storeForStore and count make a count even empty arrays:

so this is what i want to achieve,if someone ca help me plz
I made a query like that but it does not count empty values
`

```
db.getCollection("deliveryInfosDto").aggregate([
    {
         $addFields:{
              "diag.webForWeb.name" : "webForWeb",
              "diag.webForStore.name" : "webForStore",
              "diag.storeForStore.name" : "storeForStore"
         }  
    },
    {
    $project: {
      _id: "$storeId",
      businessRules: { $concatArrays: ["$diag.webForWeb", "$diag.webForStore", "$diag.storeForStore"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: { path: "$businessRules", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id:{StoreId:"$_id",bBusinessRule : "$businessRules.name", Cas: "$businessRules._id"},
      count: {$sum: 1}   
     }
  }

])
```

Comment: The document to query is missing in the question, if you haven't posted it before, please do.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right. This would give what you need.

```
db.getCollection('deliveryInfosDto').aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "storeId":"$storeId", 
        "rules" :[ { "rule":"WebForWeb", "count":{ $size: "$diag.webForWeb" }}
                            , { "rule":"WebForStore", "count":{ $size: "$diag.webForStore" }}
                            , { "rule":"StoreForStore", "count":{ $size: "$diag.storeForStore" }},]} 
   },
   { "$unwind": "$rules"},
   { "$group" : {
       "_id": {"businessRule": "$rules.rule", "storeId":"$storeId" },
       "Cas": { $sum: "$rules.count"  }}} 

])
```

Result:

```
    { 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "storeForStore", 
        "Cas" : "6"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "8"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "12"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "18"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "30"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "7"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "192", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "storeForStore", 
        "Cas" : "5"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "192", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "10"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "7"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "39"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "37"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "192", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "12"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "12"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "17"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "3"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "6"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "176", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "storeForStore", 
        "Cas" : "6"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "192", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : "18"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "192", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForWeb", 
        "Cas" : "18"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but that's not what i want, i just edited the post if you can see i have added what i expect. thanks in advance. cas in the resut is the id of the arrays values

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you want to do. Do you want to count sub-items?

Comment: storeId; WebForStore ; (vide); 100
$storeId; WebForStore ; id 205; 2
$storeId; WebForStore ; id 192; 721
...
$storeId; StoreForStore ; (vide); 100
$storeId; StoreForStore ; id 176; 1344
...
$storeId; WebForWeb; (vide); 100
$storeId; WebForWeb; id 1; 1344 thats an example for what i expect

Comment: what is "(vide)" and the numbers that end of the line?

Comment: vide mean empty, i want to count even the empty arrays

Comment: the number at the end is the count

Comment: i made an update result in my post if you can see this what i have and thats what i want just i want to count even the empty values for example i want to have plus my result this too { 
    "_id" : {
        "StoreId" : "205", 
        "bBusinessRule" : "webForStore", 
        "Cas" : ""
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}